# How can I get the session object from the layoutfile in ServiceStack?

Tags: session, servicestack

From all the other pages I can get hold of the Session object with this code:

```
@{
    var user = Request.GetSession();
}

Authenticated: @user.IsAuthenticated
```

When I try to get the session from the layout file, I get this error message "Unable to compile template. Check the Errors list for details".

I'm using self hosting on this project, and the session object isn't used in the same way as with a ASP.NET project.

Can somebody point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewPage's `GetSession<T>` to get to your session.

```
@inherits ViewPage

@{
    var user = GetSession<AuthUserSession>();
}

<h1>@user.IsAuthenticated</h1>
```

Comment: I'm using self hosting, and the session object doesn't behave in the same way as with a ASP.NET solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well...if you are just serving static content that uses a _Layout (or parent) page (ie. rendering a page that is not 'backed' by a Service, like a home page) I don't think you can retrieve the Session object since Request will be null.

If you are rendering a page backed by a Service and it uses a _Layout page I think something like this should work...

```
@{
    var auth = false;
    if (Request != null)
    {
        var key = Request.Cookies["ss-id"];
        var sess = Cache.GetSession(key.Value);
        auth = sess.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
Authenticated: @auth
```

<strike>This should work in the _Layout.cshtml file of an ASP.NET MVC/Razor application that uses ServiceStack. I have not tried it with ServiceStack.Razor.</strike>

<strike>var key = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey() ?? "";
var sess = AppHost.Resolve().Get(key)</strike>

Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using self hosting. I get an NotImplemented error with this solution (Only ASP.NET Requests accessible via Singletons are supported).

Comment: Edited answer based on additional context.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I changed the structure of my page. I'm now using @Html.Partial instead of _Layout. This works.

Comment: hmmm...what is not working? I tested it within the self-hosted Razor Rockstars project. The @Html.Partial solution seems like a good way to handle it, though.